# Смена языка в игре

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, локализация, pygame

Я реализовал небольшую игру на Pygame, в ней почти нет текста, кроме меню и надписи Game Over. Я бы хотел перевести эту игру на несколько языков, но на голову приходит только один вариант, в начале дать игроку выбрать язык, а потом в каждой строчке кода, где выводится текст сделать вот так:

```
if language == "Russian":
   text1 = "Игра закончена"
   text2 = "Нажмите Q для выхода"
   ... (другие тексты на русском)
if language == "English":
   text1 = "Game Over"
   text2 = "Press Q to quit"
   ... (другие тексты на английском)
```

А мне бы хотелось иметь несколько файлов для каждого языка, например, Russian.txt и English.txt, которые выглядят вот так:

Russian.txt:

```
Игра закончена
Нажмите Q для выхода
... (тут другой текст на русском)
```

English.txt

```
Game Over
Press Q to quit
... (тут другой текст на английском)
```

И потом в самой игре просто подключать один из нескольких файлов и брать оттуда нужные слова на нужном языке. Как это можно реализовать так, чтобы и язык было удобно менять и код чисто и понятно выглядел? Потому что дальше хотелось бы сделать игру с большим кол-во текста и там уже можно будет легко запутаться.

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать `.py` файлы на каждый язык, а надписи хранить в переменных с одним именем. В итоге, например, в `russian.py` написать `text1 = "Игра закончена"`, в `english.py` написать `text1 = "Game over"`. И импортировать из нужного файла: `if language == "Russian": from russian import text1, ... elif language == "English": from english import text1, ...`.

Comment: Для этого можно использовать модуль https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тебе бы стоило сделать несколько файлов с текстом, и у каждого отдельного текста будет одно и тоже название, содержимое которого будет вызываться в программе. в таком случае тебе стоит лишь указать программе из какого файла будет браться текст определенного названия. к примеру какой-нибудь файл lang_ru:

```
menu.main.continue = 'Начать игру'
menu.main.exit = 'Выйти'
```

ну и в lang_en:

```
menu.main.continue = 'Start game'
menu.main.exit = 'Exit'
```

ну и игра в процессе вывода текста будет загружать сам текст из указанного файла, в таком случае менять язык можно будет даже в реальном времени.

Comment: Вау, отличная идея. Правда названия надо покороче делать)